# shippedHazardousGoods=allhazardousGoods does not work

Tags: api, parameters, routes, here-api

I am having trouble with the parameter shippedHazardousGoods in the HERE routing API which gives an error if passed the value allhazardousGoods. All the other values work but not this one. I have tried different capitalisation and variations but have not had any success. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: This might be a documentation error,  as an alternative you could try shippedHazardousGoods=gas,flammable,...

Answer (score 0):

The snippet from documentation:

> Truck routing only, list of hazardous materials in the vehicle. Please refer to the enumeration type HazardousGoodTypeType for available values. Note the value ***allhazardousGoods* does not apply to the request parameter (only in response available)**.
>   Enum [explosive | gas | flammable | combustible | organic | poison | radioActive | corrosive | poisonousInhalation | harmfulToWater | other]

See please on [Documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-calculate-route.html)